# OpenCL computation times much longer than CPU alternative

Tags: opencl

I'm taking my first steps in OpenCL (and CUDA) for my internship. All nice and well, I now have working OpenCL code, but the computation times are way too high, I think. My guess is that I'm doing too much I/O, but I don't know where that could be.

The code is for the main: http://pastebin.com/i4A6kPfn, and for the kernel: http://pastebin.com/Wefrqifh I'm starting to measure time after `segmentPunten(segmentArray, begin, eind);` has returned, and I end measuring time after the last `clEnqueueReadBuffer`.

Computation time on a Nvidia GT440 is 38.6 seconds, on a GT555M 35.5, on a Athlon II X4 5.6 seconds, and on a Intel P8600 6 seconds.

Can someone explain this to me? Why are the computation times are so high, and what solutions are there for this?

What is it supposed to do: (short version) to calculate how much noiseload there is made by an airplane that is passing by.

long version: there are several Observer Points (OP) wich are the points in wich sound is measured from an airplane thas is passing by. The flightpath is being segmented in 10.000 segments, this is done at the function segmentPunten. The double for loop in the main gives OPs a coordinate. There are two kernels. The first one calculates the distance from a single OP to a single segment. This is then saved in the array "afstanden". The second kernel calculates the sound load in an OP, from all the segments.

Comment: You might have a hard time getting an answer. You don't tell us what you're trying to do and your code is so long (besides it being a mix of English and Dutch) that not many will give it a go. Could you perhaps briefly explain what your code is doing and perhaps narrow it down somewhat?

Comment: zomg, totally forgot that. Ofcourse, I'm going to write an explanation. Could take a while though

Comment: And are the CPU computation times related to the same OpenCL code running on a CPU, or are you talking about other CPU specific code?

Comment: all those computation times are from the same code. Im now going to edit the comments in pastebin to be fully English, that's maybe also helpfull :P

Comment: Could you try gradually decreasing the number of segments, to see whether the computation time scales linearly? The computation times seem very long…

Answer (score 3):

Just eyeballing your kernel, I see this:

```
kernel void SEL(global const float *afstanden, global double *totaalSEL, 
    const int aantalSegmenten)
{
    // ... 
    for(i = 0; i < aantalSegmenten; i++) {
        double distance = afstanden[threadID * aantalSegmenten + i];
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

It looks like `aantalSegmenten` is being set to 1000. You have a loop in each
kernel that accesses global memory 1000 times. Without crawling though the code,
I'm guessing that many of these accesses overlap when considering your
computation as a whole. It this the case? Will two work items access the same
global memory? If this is the case, you will see a potentially huge win on the
GPU from rewriting your algorithm to partition the work such that you can read
from a specific global memory only once, saving it in local memory. After that,
each work item in the work group that needs that location can read it quickly.

As an aside, the CL specification allows you to omit the leading `__` from CL
keywords like `global` and `kernel`.  I don't think many newcomers to CL realize
that.

Comment: I don't think I understand your answer immediately, I think I need to let it settle a bit. If you can expand your answer a bit I'd be very happy. Though the thought that the loop is quite huge is already a good one. Thanks for the tip about the __, I didn't know that ;)

Comment: I posted a refurbished kernel, but there were faults in it, so that it wasn't able to calculate anything. My mistake, my problem still isn't solved

Answer (score 1):

Before optimizing further, you should first get an understanding of what is taking all that time. Is it the kernel compiles, data transfer, or actual kernel execution?

As mentioned above, you can get rid of the kernel compiles by caching the results. I believe some OpenCL implementations (the Apple one at least) already do this automatically. With other, you may need to do the caching manually. [Here's instructions for the caching.](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=216576)

If the performance bottle neck is the kernel itself, you can probably get a major speed-up by organizing the 'afstanden' array lookups differently. Currently when a block of threads performs a read from the memory, the addresses are spread out through the memory, which is a real killer for GPU performance. You'd ideally want to index array with something like `afstanden[ndx*NUM_THREADS + threadID]`, which would make accesses from a work group to load a contiguous block of memory. This is *much* faster than the current, essentially random, memory lookup.

Comment: I don't think I completely understand what the people in the thread you linked are trying to do. First they compile the program, and write it to a file, and the second program gets that file again, and builds it, so it can run it? And the file can be permanent stored? Do I understand that correctly? Secondly I don't understand the indexing :P I'm quite new to C and OpenCL :P I have some (school-)experience in C#, but this things are way out of what is teached at our school :P

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are measuring not the computation time but the whole kernel read-in/compile/execute mumbo-jumbo. To do a fair comparison measure the computation time from the first "non-static" part of your program. (For example from between the first clSetKernelArgs to the last clEnqueueReadBuffer.)

If the execution time is still too high, then you can use some kind of profiler (such as VisualProfiler from NVidia), and read the OpenCL Best Practices guid which is included in the CUDA Toolkit documentation.

To the raw kernel execution time: Consider (and measure) that do you really need the double precision for your calculation, because the double precision calculations are artificially slowed down on the consumer grade NVidia cards.

Comment: I know I am measuring that. En that's also te meaning of it. It is used for comparison against the original C-code. So I need the complete running time of the code

Comment: Then add the compile time of your C implementation to be fair :) (Do not measure the kernel compile time, because you can save out the compiled binary representation and use again on the same gpu)

Comment: that's a good point. How do I add the compile time? I only now see that you added a comment about double precision. I really need double precision, otherwise my code doesn't seem to work. But that's not important for my project. Goal is to examine GPGPU, and to implement some code they use. Whatever way, the code they have is going to be faster with OpenCL/CUDA. I already partly solved it, see my comment on James' answer